# Problems in Displaying Datetime values in Dropdownlist razor mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

i got two fields date(datetime) and transactionID (int).

I need to fetch values of date where transactionID between 10 and 20 and display it in a dropdownlist.

I did like..

```
BFDbEntities BFT = new BFDbEntities();

var xe = (from n in BFT.Transactions where n.TRANSACTIONID > 10 where n.TRANSACTIONID < 20 select n.DATE);

List<int> items = new List<int>();

foreach (var item in xe)
 {
  **items.Add(item);**
 }

ViewBag.yearlb = new SelectList(items);
```

I get the following errors:

> Error  2   The best overloaded method match for 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(int)' has some invalid arguments  C:\Users\Santhosh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VS 2010\sampleBF\sampleBF\Controllers\HomeController.cs 94  17  sampleBF
>
> Error  3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'int' 
>   C:\Users\Santhosh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VS 2010\sampleBF\sampleBF\Controllers\HomeController.cs 94  27  sampleBF

I know its silly mistake. But am a beginner with just one week of experience.Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks !!!

Comment: I found out its because i have used 
    
    List<int> items = new List<int>();

to display datetime values.
But 

            List<DateTime> items = new List<DateTime>();

should be used. :)

Comment: When you can, please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found out its because i have used

```
List<int> items = new List<int>();
```

to display datetime values. But

```
List<DateTime> items = new List<DateTime>();
```

should be used. :)